# Python Flask & Jinja - Getting text from database

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I'm using Python with Flask and Jinja2. I am getting some text from my database (SQLITE 3) and in the database it is displayed properly with line breaks. However when I display this text on the website it all displays on one line.

It should be displayed like this:

`Hello
How are you?`

but it's appearing as:

`Hello How are you?`

Comment: Could you post your code ?

Comment: Presumably this is just because that's how HTML works, unless you add specific break tags, or put it within a `pre` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python strings, newlines are signified via the `\n` character, in HTML you need `<br />` for that. So you need to add this to your string:

```
my_string = my_string.replace("\n", "<br />)
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much :)